# How to declare a time series of weekly data?

Tags: r, date, time-series, week-number

I have a question regarding declaring my dataset as a time series. I have weekly historical data of demand of a certain product. Every week is labeled as 201401, 201402, up to the current month 201937.

The problem arises once I declare the set as  `ts <- ts(data, start=2014, frequency=52)`. Because every year consists of 365.25 days, in my set I have a week 201553. So from week 201601, every week is basically a week later, which causes problem when finding seasonality patterns.

Do I have to delete week 201553 or what is the appropriate continuation?

Answer (score 0):

If you set `frequency=365.25/7`, things should work out fine.

### References

- https://otexts.com/fpp2/ts-objects.html
- https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.1/topics/ts (interestingly, the trick with `frequency=52.17857` is not mentioned here)
- http://manishbarnwal.com/blog/2017/05/03/time_series_and_forecasting_using_R/